# python - Finding the user's "Downloads" folder

Tags: python, directory, special-folders

I already found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227590/finding-the-users-my-documents-path) that suggests to use `os.path.expanduser(path)` to get the user's home directory.

I would like to achieve the same with the "Downloads" folder. I know that [this is possible in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667012/getting-downloads-folder-in-c), yet I'm new to Python and don't know if this is possible here too, preferable platform-independent (Windows, Ubuntu).

I know that I just could do `download_folder = os.path.expanduser("~")+"/Downloads/"`, yet [(at least in Windows) it is possible to change the Default download folder](http://www.mstoic.com/how-to-change-downloads-folder-location-in-windows-7/).

Comment: With sufficient ctypes-foo you could adapt [the Windows-specific code in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7672816/1600898) to Python (with a fallback to `os.expanduser(...)` on non-Windows platforms). [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29888752/1600898) is an example. Note, however, that a "Downloads" directory is not a platform-independent concept. It is quite possible to encounter Linux systems that don't have one, so be sure to create it if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @user4815162342: Okay, thanks for the advice with `a "Downloads" directory is not a platform-independent concept.`!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Correctly locating Windows folders is somewhat of a chore in Python. According to answers covering Microsoft development technologies, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672774/how-do-i-determine-the-windows-download-folder-path/7672816#7672816), they should be obtained using the Vista [Known Folder API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776911(v=VS.85).aspx). This API is not wrapped by the Python standard library (though there is [an issue from 2008](https://bugs.python.org/issue1763) requesting it), but one can use the ctypes module to access it anyway.

Adapting the above answer to use the folder id for downloads [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672774/how-do-i-determine-the-windows-download-folder-path/7672816#7672816) and combining it with your existing Unix code should result in code that looks like this:

```
import os

if os.name == 'nt':
    import ctypes
    from ctypes import windll, wintypes
    from uuid import UUID

    # ctypes GUID copied from MSDN sample code
    class GUID(ctypes.Structure):
        _fields_ = [
            ("Data1", wintypes.DWORD),
            ("Data2", wintypes.WORD),
            ("Data3", wintypes.WORD),
            ("Data4", wintypes.BYTE * 8)
        ] 

        def __init__(self, uuidstr):
            uuid = UUID(uuidstr)
            ctypes.Structure.__init__(self)
            self.Data1, self.Data2, self.Data3, \
                self.Data4[0], self.Data4[1], rest = uuid.fields
            for i in range(2, 8):
                self.Data4[i] = rest>>(8-i-1)*8 & 0xff

    SHGetKnownFolderPath = windll.shell32.SHGetKnownFolderPath
    SHGetKnownFolderPath.argtypes = [
        ctypes.POINTER(GUID), wintypes.DWORD,
        wintypes.HANDLE, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_wchar_p)
    ]

    def _get_known_folder_path(uuidstr):
        pathptr = ctypes.c_wchar_p()
        guid = GUID(uuidstr)
        if SHGetKnownFolderPath(ctypes.byref(guid), 0, 0, ctypes.byref(pathptr)):
            raise ctypes.WinError()
        return pathptr.value

    FOLDERID_Download = '{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}'

    def get_download_folder():
        return _get_known_folder_path(FOLDERID_Download)
else:
    def get_download_folder():
        home = os.path.expanduser("~")
        return os.path.join(home, "Downloads")
```

A more complete module for retrieving known folders from Python is [available on github](https://gist.github.com/mkropat/7550097).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed investigation and the link to the issue.

Comment: @MarkusWeninger You might also want to take a look at [this more complete wrapper](https://gist.github.com/mkropat/7550097) for `SHGetKnownFolderPath`.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into it. `get_download_folder()` currently crashes with the following error. `File ".\downloadfolders.py", line 34, in _get_known_folder_path
    if SHGetKnownFolderPath(ctypes.byref(guid), 0, 0, ctypes.byref(pathptr)):
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 4: <class 'TypeError'>: expected LP_c_char_p instance instead of pointer to c_wchar_p`

Comment: Yes, `print(get_download_folder())` now prints my download folder (using Windows 10). Thanks a lot again, a pitty I cannot upvote again ;)

Comment: @MarkusWeninger You're welcome. Answer amended to remove the "untested" claim. :)

Comment: The issue is now closed solved claiming that the appdirs module solves the problem. Appdirs has since been superseded by the platformdirs module. The modules address some directory concepts but not the downloads directory. I can't find another Python module that does.

Answer (score 50):

```
from pathlib import Path
downloads_path = str(Path.home() / "Downloads")
```

Comment: I am pretty sure this does not account for relocation on Windows as per the OP. In fact, I am pretty sure that Windows does not actually require the Downloads directory to be located within anything that looks like a "home" directory.

Comment: Yes not only can the Windows Downloads directory be renamed or moved, on non-English systems it is localized into another language even in a fresh, default setup.

Answer (score 23):

This fairly simple solution (expanded from [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/4dfh1i/how_to_get_the_downloads_folder_path_on_windows/) reddit post) worked for me

```
import os

def get_download_path():
    """Returns the default downloads path for linux or windows"""
    if os.name == 'nt':
        import winreg
        sub_key = r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders'
        downloads_guid = '{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}'
        with winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sub_key) as key:
            location = winreg.QueryValueEx(key, downloads_guid)[0]
        return location
    else:
        return os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'downloads')
```

- The GUID can be obtained from Microsoft's [`KNOWNFOLDERID` docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457(v=vs.85).aspx)
- This can be expanded to work more generically other directories

Comment: But this would find the downloads folder path of a local server. How do you find the downloads folder of the client if the same is to be acheived for a web app?

Comment: you cannot do this server side for obvious reasons - you will need to embed some kind of script in your web app that is ran by the end user's browser

Comment: Most linux distributions are case sensitive, and most linux distributions name the folder with a capital 'D'.  Therefore, adding a lower case 'downloads' to the user path doesn't work.  You should use 'Downloads' instead.

Answer (score 13):

For python3+  mac or linux

```
from pathlib import Path
path_to_download_folder = str(os.path.join(Path.home(), "Downloads"))
```

Comment: The downloads folder is localized on Windows so non-English systems call it something else. Furthermore the user can rename it or move it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Some linux distributions localize the name of the Downloads folder. E.g. after changing my locale to `zh_TW`, the Downloads folder became `/home/user/下載`. The correct way on linux distributions (using xdg-utils from freedesktop.org) is to call `xdg-user-dir`:

```
import subprocess
# Copy windows part from other answers here
try:
    folder = subprocess.run(["xdg-user-dir", "DOWNLOAD"],
                            capture_output=True, text=True).stdout.strip("\n")
except FileNotFoundError:  # if the command is missing
    import os.path
    folder = os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads")  # fallback
```

Note that the use of `capture_output` requires Python ≥3.7.
If you already use GLib or don't mind adding more dependencies, see also
[these approaches using packages.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457047/how-can-i-get-the-xdg-default-user-directories-from-python)

Comment: Out of interest, which Linux distro are you using that does this?

Comment: @hippietrail: Ubuntu does this.

Answer (score 1):

For python3 on windows try:

```
import os

folder = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 'folder_name')
print(folder)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this so it can check the downloads folder even if device's language is not english:

```
from pathlib import Path
from googletrans import Translator


translator = Translator()
downloads = "Downloads"
downloads_path = str(Path.home() / downloads)

if str(downloads_path.split("\\")[-1]) != downloads:
    en_path = translator.translate(str(downloads_path.split("\\")[-1]), dest="en")
    if en_path.text == "downloads" or en_path.text == "Downloads":
        downloads_path = str(Path.home() / str(en_path.text))
```