# assert os.path.isfile only working with full path

Tags: python, splinter

I've been given an educational assignment during which I write Gherkin scenarios to test a website using Python 3.6, Splinter and Behave. I'm making some pretty good progress but I'm stuck on this little thing. Currently I've succeeded in getting a file to download through a headless instance of Chrome in Ubuntu. However, for the last step of the scenario to pass, I need to verify the file's existence. After a lot of searching I've found a method that works, which is:

```
assert os.path.isfile('/home/[USERNAME]/Downloads/file.csv')
```

However, in order to make this test more compatible with other computers, I'd like the path to the file to be shorter and simpler. Most importantly, not using this system's username.

I'm new to all of this so this could very well be a dumb question, but I've been searching all over the place and I simply can't find an answer.

Comment: Did you try to use "os.path.realpath(file)"  to get the real path for your file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rewrite the path using the `~` which replaces `/home/[USERNAME]/`, so it would become `~/Downloads/file.csv`. Then, you could use Python's `os.path.expanduser()` function as follows:

```
assert os.path.isfile(os.path.expanduser('~/Downloads/file.csv'))
```

`os.path.expanderuser()` will automatically expand it to `/home/[USERNAME]/` for you.

Comment: Thank you! I knew I was very close having tried multiple os.path options, but this I hadn't yet. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get Downloads folder path, than you can use answer to this question: [python - Finding the user's "Downloads" folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35851281/python-finding-the-users-downloads-folder)