# Any universal keyword to be use in place of user's name folder in directory in Windows

Tags: python, directory

I'm trying to make a video downloader python program on windows. In my computer, the download folder is in C:\Users\Suraj\Downloads. If someone else uses my code in their computer, the download folder is in C:\Users*XYZ\Downloads. How to solve this directory problem(Suraj, XYZ)?

Comment: This answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35851281/python-finding-the-users-downloads-folder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python - Finding the user's "Downloads" folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35851281/python-finding-the-users-downloads-folder)

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks that you are looking for `os.path.expanduser`, which can be used following way:

```
import os
homepath = os.path.expanduser('~')
downloadspath = os.path.expanduser(os.path.join('~','Downloads'))
```

according to [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) it should work in `Linux` as well `Windows`, but I did not test second, so please test it before use.

Comment: User may have changed the location of Downloads folder, though.