# How to return a windows user directory if it was moved to a different drive in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Still very new to Python.
Within Windows using Python 3.7.

I would like to have a way of using Python to find windows user directories e.g. "Downloads" that have been moved to a secondary drive using the supported windows method.

As described by

https://www.windowscentral.com/how-move-default-user-folders-new-drive-windows-10

I prefer not to use Symlinks for this though it would bypass the issue.

Currently I use as

```
os.path.expanduser('~/Downloads')
```

This returns the default user folder say `C:/Users/user/`
followed by the folder mentioned `C:/Users/user/downloads` rather than linking to the user defined default folder for downloads in this case say `D:/user/Downloads`.

Could you please advise me on the right approach?

Comment: Have you tried using the direct path name?

Comment: Aren’t you supposed to use the `%NAMES%` for localization support anyway?

Comment: I built a workaround that manually searches both "user folders" for windows and defaults to `os.path.expanduser()` for other OS's. I like coding reusable function "libraries" for reference so prefer a more flexible method. There appears to be a more complete method involving obtaining it from the registry using the GUID (KNOWNFOLDERID) of the folder using the winreg library. I just expected a simpler method to exist. I found it at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35851281/python-finding-the-users-downloads-folder#35851955) after rephrasing the question a few times.

Comment: Regarding the `%NAMES%` comment by Davis somehow accessing `%HOMEPATH%` directly would provide a simpler solution but I do not know of any method to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows stores these paths in environment variables. You should be able to access those in Python using e.g. `os.getenv('HOMEPATH')`. If it's not in a variable, you may be able to find it in the Windows registry. You can access that using the `winreg` module in the standard library (in Windows distributions only, of course).

Comment: `homepath = os.getenv('HOMEPATH')
homepath = os.path.realpath(homepath+'/Downloads')`
Produced the desired result. Thank you.