# How to set the path of a file to work in any machine?

Tags: python, json, file

Lets say I want to save some content in a JSON file, like this:

```
 with open('C:\\Users\\my_user\\Downloads\\test.json','w') as new_f:
        json.dump(found_database, new_f, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

And I want to save it into the Downloads folder of the users' machine.

How can I set the path to the Downloads folder not knowing the user/computer name?
Something like this:

```
with open('C:\\Users\\%user name%\\Downloads\\test.json','w') as new_f:
```

If the user is from a different country, like an Asian one, does the structure of the path changes? I mean, do they use the same backslash as we use to do it? If not, is there a way to make the path work in any machine, no matter the country?

Also, for instance, in Brazil they use **C:\Usuários** instead of **C:\Users**. Is this a problem when trying to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: This might be helpful to you; https://stackoverflow.com/a/48706260/5594257

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python - Finding the user's "Downloads" folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35851281/python-finding-the-users-downloads-folder)

Comment: I found this and i think it might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/35851955/12678128