# How to set 'Downloads' folder as default directory for python pafy downloads

Tags: python, video, module, download, pafy

I have a code that downloads video with python pafy module

At default it downloads the video in where my `.py` file is. But I want the Windows `Downloads` Folder as the destination of the downloaded video. How can I do it? Thanks in Advance

```
import pafy

url = "video_url"
video = pafy.new(url)

#all streams
streams = video.streams

#best video
best = video.getbest()

#download
try:
    best.download()
except Exception as e:
    print ("Error Downloading video")
else:
    print ("Video Downloaded Successfully")
```

Comment: Here's [how to change the current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/431684/5675325). You'd want to change it right before downloading.

Comment: What if I want to make it an app and in others computer how can I know there donwload directory folder?

Comment: That's a different question than what you asked... but [that's not something new](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35851281/5675325).

Comment: Oh.... But that is in my mind lol

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments.

Initially I thought that you wanted to change the current directory in your machine. Hence, I referenced [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/431684/5675325) where we can read [answers like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/431715/5675325) which states that the desired operation can be achieved with

```
import os

os.chdir(path)
```

OFC in your particular case you'd want to change the path right before downloading the file.

Since you added more clarification with

> What if I want to make it an app and in others computer how can I know
> there donwload directory folder?

that'd be a different scenario and there's an already existing [question for that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35851281/5675325) too with an already [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35851955/5675325).