# How to access Linux's downloads folder using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, directory, distro

In ubuntu the downloads folder is located in home\ubuntu\Downloads, but I don't know if different distros have the same "style" (eg. home\arch\Downloads). Is there a "universal path" for all distros?
For anyone wondering i need to make a new directory in downloads.

Comment: Actually it is located under user's path. You can easily access it by `~/Downloads`, where `~` means user's home folder. YOu can get the absolute path of user's home directory in python.

Comment: I reopened the question because this [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35851281/15239951) are not satisfactory in my opinion. `freedesktop` is never mentioned although it's a standard now under Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "home directory" (functionally similar to `C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME` on Windows) is at `/home/YOUR_USERNAME` on *most* Linux distros, and this is where the Downloads folder is located usually. The way to be the most sure about getting the correct directory is by using `pathlib.Path.home()`:

```py
from pathlib import Path
downloads_path = str(Path.home() / "Downloads")
```

[Taken from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62662388/9211949)

Comment: Oh, this makes sense now. I've named my ubuntu user "ubuntu"

Comment: On some Linux distros, [including Ubuntu apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35851281/python-finding-the-users-downloads-folder/74231751#comment133999866_72591013) this directory name is localized into the OS install language or user's language (not sure which).

Answer (score 3):

On Linux, you can use [`xdg-user-dir`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-user-dirs/) from freedesktop.org project. It should work on every recent Desktop environments (KDE, Gnome, etc) and all recent distributions:

```
import shutil
import subprocess

xdg_bin = shutil.which('xdg-user-dir')
process = subprocess.run([xdg_bin, 'DOWNLOAD'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
download_path = process.stdout.strip().decode()
print(download_path)

# Output:
/home/corralien/Downloads
```

If you have Python 3.7 or higher, you can use the `capture_output=True` argument instead of the `stdout` argument.