# Renaming a file in Downloads Folder using Python

Tags: python, excel, windows, date, time

I'm trying to rename a file using Python code that is in Downloads folder but I keep receiving below error. I cannot find the absolute path.

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '~/Downloads/Test.xlsx' -> 'Test_2023-01-25 14:04:51.552908.xlsx'

Here is the code:

```
import os
import datetime
dt = str(datetime.datetime.now())

newname = 'Test_'+dt+'.xlsx'
os.rename('~/Downloads/Test.xlsx', newname)
```

Appreciate all the help I can get. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: This may be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35851281/python-finding-the-users-downloads-folder . The "~" symbol is throwing it off.

Comment: Thanks @MarcMorcos, I checked this article earlier and I have to test each answers.

Comment: can't still figure out the script to resolve the issue. maybe its just me, tried possible solution from this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35851281/python-finding-the-users-downloads-folder

Comment: If you dont need this to be general you can put the true absolute path yourself. On windows it would be something like C:/Users/yourusername/Downloads